# Linear transformation on polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

For a positive integer $n,$ let $P_n$ denotes the space of all polynomials $p(x)$ with coefficients in $\mathbb R$ such that deg$p(x)\le n,$ and let $B_n$ denotes the standard basis of $P_n$ given by $B_n=\{1,x,x^2,...,x^n\}.$ If $T:P_3\to P_4$ is the linear transformation defined by $T(p(x))=x^2p'(x)+\int_0^x p(t)dt$ and $A=(a_{ij})$ is the $5\times4$ matrix of $T$ with respect to standard basis $B_3$ and $B_4$, then which of the following is correct?

$1.$ $a_{32}=\frac32$ and $a_{33}=\frac73$

$2.$ $a_{32}=\frac32$ and $a_{33}=0$

$3.$ $a_{32}=0$ and $a_{33}=\frac73$

$4.$ $a_{32}=0$ and $a_{33}=0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$T(1)=x$, $T(x)=\frac32x^2$, $T(x^2)=\frac73x^3$, $T(x^3)=\frac{13}4x^4$

So, the $5\times4$ is: $\begin{bmatrix}0 &0 &0& 0\\
  1& 0& 0& 0\\
0 &\frac32& 0& 0\\
0& 0& \frac73& 0\\
0& 0& 0& \frac{13}4\end{bmatrix}$. Here, $a_{32}=\frac32$ and $a_{33}=0$.

Comment: +1 Well done. You probably came very close to receiving comments asking "what have you done?", "is this homework?" and the like, but you escaped by coming up with an answer yourself. Good job!

Comment: I am having $1km$ long smile :)